# Assign a list of values to a list of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I want to assign some new values to specific indices using Numpy. I can do this easily with a for-loop:

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.arange(5)
new_vals = np.array([-1, -2])
ind = np.array([1, 3])

for i in list(ind):
    vals[i] = new_vals[i]
```

But how do I accomplish this in a vectorized manner? Something like

```
np.splat(vals[ind], new_vals)
```

Comment: As an aside, I couldn't decide whether this question should be SO or CodeReview.SE. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is quite specific, and your code is quite examplish, so I (as a mod on Code Review) think this question is better on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple indexing:

```
>>> vals[ind] = new_vals
>>> vals
array([ 0, -1,  2, -2,  4])
```

Comment: I don't know why I thought this wouldn't work. I'll mark you answer as correct soon. \*facepalm\*

Comment: @Seanny123 That's the power of Numpy :).